# How do I use AutoMapper to populate back to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, dto

I'm using AutoMapper which is a great tool.

There's lots of examples converting from `DataTable`/`IDataRead` **to** `DTO`'s but I can't seem to find any that convert the `DTO` **back** to a `DataTable`.

Is this possible?  I've tried various things, but I think there's some difficulty with the creation of `Row`s - as you can't `new` them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked it in GIT; Jimmy Bogard may be looking to merge it in during the next major version.

You can get it [here](http://github.com/SteveDunn/AutoMapper).

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Have you ever found a solution? If so, could you please provide an example? Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Not right now out of the box.  What you COULD do is create a new IObjectMapper.  Take a look at the DataReaderMapper.cs in the source code (found on github), and build the opposite direction.  If you get it to work, I'll gladly fold what you get back into the project, because it sounds like a really interesting idea.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy.  I've been taking a look today and it looks as though the enumerable mapper is better suited.  I know I'm probably wrong though!  Also, I'm not sure if the IL generated stuff is needed as we'd be mapping from a strongly typed object into a DataTable.  Wouldn't mind a bit of help if you've got time.  I'll buy you beer 'till it comes out of your ears if we meet some-day at a conference or something! :)